# Could anyone help me find the EXACT value?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

Could anyone please help me find the EXACT value (not numerical value) of this by Mathematica or by mathematical reasoning? Thanks a lot.

```
Maximize[Min[Abs[Sin[a]], Abs[Cos[a]], Abs[Sin[a - b]], 
  Abs[Cos[a - b]], Abs[Sin[b]], Abs[Cos[b]], Abs[Sin[a - c]], 
  Abs[Cos[a - c]], Abs[Sin[b - c]], Abs[Cos[b - c]], Abs[Sin[c]], 
  Abs[Cos[c]]], {a, b, c}]
```

Comment: $\sin(\pi/8)$ would appear to be the winner.

Answer (score 2):

```
NMaximize[Min[Abs[Sin[a]], Abs[Cos[a]], Abs[Sin[a - b]], Abs[Cos[a - b]], 
  Abs[Sin[b]], Abs[Cos[b]], Abs[Sin[a - c]], Abs[Cos[a - c]], 
  Abs[Sin[b - c]], Abs[Cos[b - c]], Abs[Sin[c]], Abs[Cos[c]]], {a, b, c}]

(*    {0.382683, {a -> -0.392699, b -> 0.392699, c -> -0.785398}}    *)
```

These values are exactly

```
(*    {Sin[π/8], {a -> -π/8, b -> π/8, c -> -π/4}}    *)
```

There are many equivalent solutions, forming an interesting grid in space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just wondering, how do you know the maximizer that NMaximize finds is a global maximizer? and how to rigorously show that the exact value must be Sin[π/8]? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can never know if [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) gets stuck in a local extremum or finds the global one. Some of the options, like `Method`, can help greatly; also, doing a [`ContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) can give you an idea if there are any regions of higher values. For a rigorous answer you need to go to the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).